# Question regarding the number of path-connected components of a compact space .

Tags: general-topology, compactness, path-connected

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $(\mathbb R^n, \tau)$ denotes the standard topology on $\mathbb R^n$ . Does there exist any compact subspace $S$ , not totally disconnected, and any $n \in \mathbb N(\gt 1)$ such that the number of path-connected components of $S$ is exactly $\aleph_0$ ???
Also, same problem for number of path-connected components being $2^{\aleph_0} .$

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ As the standard topology of $\mathbb R^n$ is metrizable, hence $S$ must be closed and $\mathbf {bounded}$ . But, I am confused how to produce an example of a bounded set to have number of path-connected components $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0} .$

Please provide me a small hint about either a counter-example, if exists or how to disprove .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ has countably many connected components. And the Cantor set has uncountably many. Finally, both of them are compact.

Comment: Sir, can you please provide examples of spaces which are not totally disconnected but satisfying the stated property ???

Comment: Sure: take any of my sets and add the interval $[2,3]$ to it.

Comment: Sir, can you please provide me some more non-trivial examples rather than Cantor sets or something relating to it???

Comment: No, I cannot, and I doubt that such an example exists.

Comment: Okay, Sir, I will try it, and if you can get a morsel amount of time to think about this problem, please see it and if you get any results, please inform me , Thanks, too much !!!